# Why constant mean curvature surfaces are isothermal surfaces?

Tags: differential-geometry, minimal-surfaces

From the Encyclopedia of Mathematics [website](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Isothermal_surface), I read that constant mean curvature (CMC) surfaces, in particular minimal surfaces, are isothermal surfaces, i.e. a surface whose curvature lines form an [isothermal net](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Isothermal_net). But how can I prove this?

Edit: From the comment by @WillJagy, I see from the Weierstrass–Enneper parameterization, curvature lines of minimal surfaces are isothermal coordinates. But what about a general CMC surface?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass%E2%80%93Enneper_parameterization

Comment: @WillJagy Thank you for commenting. From this page, I can see that $X_u$ and $X_v$ is an isothermal coordinate of the minimal surface. But in order to show that the minimal surface is an isothermal surface, I still need to prove the curvature lines form an isothermal net. How can I do this?